# NetBeans + Scala + Maven

Tags: scala, maven, netbeans, sbt

I am new to Scala and relatively new to Java.  I can't seem to get dialed into using an IDE with Scala.  I'm using a plain text editor and using sbt, which has worked great.  But I'd like to have code hints, and let the IDE help me resolve classes by searching for them in maven.

I have the Scala plugin for NetBeans working, but it uses ant.  Code hints work, but it doesn't resolve classes for me like it does using java/maven.

Is there a way to use NetBeans with Scala using Maven or SBT?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a NetBeans user but I wanted to test it with a maven setup and for me it worked well with the following pom file.

It uses [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) for the unit tests.

I just loaded this project by choosing `Open project...` and pointed to the pom file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow.Q13337089</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scala.version>2.9.2</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.9.2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.M4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-test</id>
                        <!-- Disable the default-test by putting it in phase none -->
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-M2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                    <stdout>W</stdout> <!-- Skip coloring output -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I have a similar file, but I don't see any code-completion and run-file doesn't work. Run project works sometimes, otherwise I get NoClassDefFoundError. Have you had any luck with `netbeans` & `maven` ?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dcaoyuan/nbscala#readme should in some incaarnation include code bridging the scala support with maven projects. the netbeans module is there in source code, not sure if it's someplace as binary.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. 
**First**  install netbeans > 7.4
**Second** install scala plugin from [netbeans plugins website](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/54162/nbscala-1-6-3-1) follow the directions to add the plugin.
**third** create a Maven project. New Project-> Maven -> Project From Archetype. Then choose "scala archetype simple", then "Next" and "finish".

Answer (score 0):

I've had a much better time with the Scala IDE with eclipse. That is really all you need if you are just trying to get a project going.

There is also an sbt plugin now for eclipse (though I've not bothered using that, as the eclipse plugin for sbt generates eclipse project files very nicely).

If you want to go from an sbt build file INTO eclipse, then I can tell you that I do webapp devel with Lift (starting with an sbt build template), and I did my setup according to these instructions, which include integrating it into eclipse:

http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/lift24scalaide20/index.html

Actually, the [top-level tutorials](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/index.html) directory has instructions for doing Play, Android devel, and others using the Scala IDE.